# How to show whether 3 planes have a common line of intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

To show whether or not the 3 planes
$$x+y-2z=5\tag 1$$ 
$$x-y+3z=6 \tag2$$ 
$$x+5y-12z=12 \tag 3$$ all have a common line of intersection.

Can I do $(3)-(2)$ to get the line $6y-15z=6$ and $(1)-(2)$ to get the line $2y-5z=-1$ which is $6y-15z=-3$ , and say that as these aren't the same line, they don't have a common line of intersection?

Another thing that is confusing me is that if instead of eliminating $x$, I chose to eliminate $z$, I would get different lines in terms of $x$ and $y$. But how can I get the equations of two different lines by eliminating from the same pair of plane equations? There's only one line of intersection between any pair of planes, so surely I should only be able to get one unique line if I eliminate a variable from a pair of planes? 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Note that adding/subtracting two planes does not give you the line of intersection. It only gives you another plane passing through the line of intersection of the two.

Comment: But if you eliminate one variable, you get a line. What is the significance of that line?

Comment: It is not a line. The general equation of a plane is $ax+by+cz=d$ where in your case, one of the coefficients is $0$.

Comment: Hint: First write the augmented matrix; then by elementary-row transformation, convert it to reduced echelon form. If the rightmost- column is not a pivot column, then the three planes intersect each other.

Comment: It means that some of these planes just don't intersect with each other.

Answer (score 6):

**An elementary solution and notes to the OP**

If $3$ planes have a unique common point then they don't have a common straight line. In order to see if there is a common line we have to see if we can solve the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{matrix}
x+y&-2z&=&5\\
x-y&+3z&=&6\\
\ x+5y&-12z&=&12.
\end{matrix}
$$
Adding the first equation to the second one we get $$2x+z=11.$$
Multiplying the second equation by $5$ and then adding it to the third equation we get $$3x+z=21.$$
These two equations have a unique solution:
$$x=10\text { and } z=-9.$$
Substituting these numbers back to any of the original equations we get $y=-23$.

So, the three planes have a unique common point; no common line exists.

**Notes to the OP**

If you take, say, $(1)$ and $(2)$ and eliminate one of the variables, say $x$ then you get an equation of a straight line in the plane $zy$.

This line is a perpendicular projection of the common line of  $(1)$ and $(2)$ to $yz$. **If** the planes $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ have a unique point then all of the possible eliminations will result in a triplet of straight lines in the different coordinate planes.

By erecting a perpendiculars from the common points of the said line triplets you will get back to the common point of the three planes.

I hope that this brief explanation helped you to understand better your own efforts.

Comment: (+1) Generally, if you write down the augmented matrix (as in user36790's comment) and reduce to echelon form, the intersection is a line _if and only if_ the system is consistent and has exactly one free variable. :)

Comment: Error in "An elementary solution and notes..."
"Multiplying the second equation by 5 and then adding it to the third equation we get 3x+z=21" Don't we get 2x+z=14, showing prism rather than unique point?

Comment: Correct, @John. We get $6x + 3z = 42$, and dividing that by $3$ yields $2x + z = 14$. That is incompatible with the first two equations, thus the three planes have no point in common.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Find normal vectors of the planes and check if three of them are linearly independent. If there is a common line for all the planes, then their normal vectors will lie within the same plane, therefore three of them will **not** be linearly independent.

---

In your specific case, 
$$
x+y-2z=5\implies \vec{n}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ -2\end{bmatrix}\\
x-y+3z=6\implies \vec{n}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -1\\ 3\end{bmatrix}\\
x+5y-12z=5\implies \vec{n}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 5\\ -12\end{bmatrix} 
$$
First, we need to check if the system of vector $\left\{\vec{n}_1, \vec{n}_2, \vec{n}_3 \right\}$ is clearly independent or not. The simplest way to do that is to compute rank of the matrix $\left[\vec{n}_1 \ \vec{n}_2\ \vec{n}_3 \right]$:
$$
\operatorname{rank}\Big(\left[\vec{n}_1 \ \vec{n}_2\ \vec{n}_3 \right]\Big) = \operatorname{rank}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1& 1 \\
1 & -1 & 5 \\
-2& 3 & -12 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If $\ \operatorname{rank}\!\left(\vec{n}_1 \ \vec{n}_2\ \vec{n}_3 \right)=2$, then the normal vectors are linearly dependent, yet still span a plane.

Second, we need to find out if there is a point common for all three planes.

If you can find a common point **and** the rank of system of normal vectors is 3, then there is a line shared by all three planes.

Comment: Careful: Your condition is necessary but not sufficient: Three planes whose normals form a linearly dependent set can be parallel, or can intersect along distinct lines (so the triple intersection is empty). With row reduction of an augmented matrix, (in)consistency of the system is a byproduct. :)

Answer (score 0):

first by solving 2 planes find y and z, where u have to consider z as t, hence u'l get parametric equation of y and z w.r.t t. now put this value in any plane which will give u parametric equation of x in terms of t only. Now substitute this values in any sphere, than u'll get quadratic equation in terms of t, if it is line than it will have two values, by which using which u can find the exact two points of intersection. Try it, it works.
tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQ0Z9yDvvsc) and [here](http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Sphere/SpherLineIntersection_.htm).