# On Condition for the Three Planes

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

This a problem taken in one of the standard text book in calculus. This is is not a homework. Can I ask some tips on how to proceed? I tried looking on the net but cant find a good one.

**Problem.** Find a condition that the three planes 
\begin{align}
a_1x+b_1y+c_1z+d_1=0\\
a_2x+b_1y+c_2z+d_2=0\\
a_3x+b_1y+c_3z+d_3=0
\end{align}
either have a line in common or have a point in common.

Comment: How much linear algebra do you know?

Comment: @ Guacho Perez Only a little, but I can review it again for the sake of this problem

Comment: You can set this up as a matrix and then use Gaussian elimination to find the rank of the matrix. If the matrix has rank 3, then they will have a point in common, if it has rank 2, they will have a line in common.

Comment: Gaucho is correct.  This is more of a linear algebra question than a calculus question.  Gaussian elimination should do the trick.

Comment: @ Guacho Perez Thank you. Maybe the one that I'm looking is a proof that you stated in your comment. Is this result can be found in a textbook, if so then I got to study it later.

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287692/how-to-show-whether-3-planes-have-a-common-line-of-intersection#

Comment: @Rohan thanks for pointing that reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the condition as a system of linear equations. If $Det A\neq 0$ in 
non-homogeneous case, the system has unique solution, that is the planes has a common point, if not it can be have $2$ or $1$ independent equation, if there is $2$ independent equation they have a common line, by   Gaussian elimination method you can find the number of independent equations. in the case $1$ independent equation the plans are the same.